# jQuery alert message with user-defined persistance?

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I'd like to set up an alert message that appears at the top of my application on the first time a user accesses it, and persists until the user dismisses it.

I'm kinda new to jQuery, but I'd like to use it for this. Does jQuery have some built in methods for this kind of thing? Ideally I'd like it to be an instant action, rather than a form variable.

My app is a PHP based WordPress plugin.

Comment: Cookies aren't very perminent, so client side would have issues with the message reappearing when not desired. Sessions aren't perminent either. Do your users have to log in to your site? The best way would be to store whether the message has been acknowledged in a database along with their user info or something. You'd AJAX a message to PHP telling it to set the database when they acknowledge the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a twitter-like alert by following the steps on these tutorials.

**CSS:**

```
#alert
{
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 0;
    color: #000;
    font: 20px/40px arial, sans-serif;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

**jQuery**

Check if
Use setTimeout to collapse the alert after 3 seconds
Expand the alert to CSS line-height or 50px if line-height is not set
If the user clicks alert before 3 seconds, collapse the alert early

```
$(function () {
    var $alert = $('#alert');
    if($alert.length)
    {
        var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $alert.trigger('click');
        }, 3000);
        $alert.animate({height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px'}, 200)
        .click(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
            $alert.animate({height: '0'}, 200);
        });
    }
});
```

**Put CSS and jQuery in an HTML page**

Some things to note:

Line 1: Turn on session with PHP
Line 13: There’s our alert CSS
Line 30: If $_SESSION['alert'] exists (set in submit.php in step 2)
Line 40: Use jQuery hosted by Google
Line 42: There’s our alert jQuery

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Twitter-like alert message</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color: #ccc;
            color: #000;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        #alert
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            height: 0;
            color: #000;
            font: 20px/40px arial, sans-serif;
            opacity: .9;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(!empty($_SESSION['display']))
        {
            echo '<div id="alert">' . $_SESSION['display'] . '</div>';
            unset($_SESSION['display']);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <label for="message">Message</label> <input type="text" name="message"> <input type="submit" value="Alert me!">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $alert = $('#alert');
            if($alert.length)
            {
                var alerttimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $alert.trigger('click');
                }, 3000);
                $alert.animate({height: $alert.css('line-height') || '50px'}, 200)
                .click(function () {
                    window.clearTimeout(alerttimer);
                    $alert.animate({height: '0'}, 200);
                });
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Use PHP to add the alert to the $_SESSION**

Save this file as submit.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$themessage = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ?
    stripslashes(trim($_POST['message'])) :
    trim($_POST['message']);

$_SESSION['display'] = $themessage;

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
?>
```

It will create something similar to this 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbJeYdPRKXw&feature=player_embedded

Comment below if you have any questions on the code, I guess this is all you need.

Credits to:
http://briancray.com/2009/05/06/twitter-style-alert-jquery-cs-php/
http://www.achari.in/create-twitter-alert-style-using-jquery-js-and-css

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage to control when the box is dismissed to never show it again. For browsers which don't support localStorage (if any that you care), use an indefinite cookie.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('Yo, click me');
```

with a cookie and/or session variable to determine if the alert should be issued or not.